# Gbrowse not working correctly on MAC

Tags: vim, git, github

I'm using `vim` and have installed Pathogen and vim-fugative, but when editing a file under source control on github.com I use the command `:Gbrowse` and nothing happens.

I've tried most of the advice I can find on the web about setting up particular browsers on the web but none of it worked. So I tried looking at the script that was trying to start up the browser (so I have removed references about the browser from `.gitconfig`).

So I found the shell script: `git-web--browse` and modified it to generate logging statements to a log file (to see if I could work out what was going on).

But when I use `:Gbrowse` I get no logging statements (so it looks like vim is not even calling this script).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

#### Info

System Mac OS X (10.9.5)

```
$ uname -a
Darwin Martins-MacBook-Pro.local 13.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim

$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 24 2013 18:58:47)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
-conceal +cryptv +cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con +diff +digraphs
-dnd -ebcdic -emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search -farsi +file_in_path
+find_in_path +float +folding -footer +fork() -gettext -hangul_input +iconv
+insert_expand +jumplist -keymap -langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent
+listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname +mouse -mouseshape
-mouse_dec -mouse_gpm -mouse_jsbterm -mouse_netterm -mouse_sysmouse
+mouse_xterm +multi_byte +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg -osfiletype
+path_extra -perl +persistent_undo +postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn
-python3 +quickfix +reltime -rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs
+smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary
+tag_old_static -tag_any_white -tcl +terminfo +termresponse +textobjects +title
 -toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo
+vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu +windows +writebackup -X11 -xfontset -xim -xsmp
 -xterm_clipboard -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0 -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe
Linking: gcc -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -o vim -lncurses
```

I have installed Pathogen and, in `~/.vimrc`:

```
 19 ¬
 20 ¬
 21 execute pathogen#infect()¬
```

In `~/.vim/bundle`:

```
$ ls -l ~/.vim/bundle/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  13 Loki  staff  442 Oct  4 15:18 gundo.vim
drwxr-xr-x   9 Loki  staff  306 Oct  4 14:08 tabular
drwxr-xr-x   8 Loki  staff  272 Oct 26  2012 vim-colors-solarized
drwxr-xr-x   8 Loki  staff  272 Oct  4 17:59 vim-fugitive
drwxr-xr-x   7 Loki  staff  238 Oct  4 13:43 vim-unimpaired
```

Comment: Sounds like this bug, potentially: https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/530

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with the version of vim that comes with OSX.

You're better off installing a newer version of vim from homebrew

```
brew install vim
```

Beware if you're using RVM though as Ruby plugins might segfault if you compile them against anything other than the system Ruby. Best this if you use RVM.

```
rvm use system; brew install vim
```

You should also find that the homebrew vim has useful features like +clipboard support etc.